# Converting video to .mp4 with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
var converter = require('converter');

converter.convert({
  from: 'avi',
  to: 'mp4',
  path: '/myvideo.avi',
  newPath: '/newvideo.mp4',
  error: function(err) {},
  success: function() {
    console.log('success!');
  }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: There are a handful of resources already available on NPM: https://www.npmjs.org/package/stream-transcoder https://www.npmjs.org/package/codem-transcode https://www.npmjs.org/package/transcoding

Answer (score 5):

Well, for one [converter](https://github.com/assemble/converter) converts between `xml`, `json`, and `yaml`. So, you won't be able to convert an avi to an mp4 with that.

However, I have used node to spawn a child [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) process for this very thing. Just an fyi, if you do choose to use ffmpeg via a [child process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) and want to watch the log for progress and debugging, you will need to watch `stderr`. Ffmpeg reserves `stdout` to optionally stream the output of the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

**FFMPEG** is good thing for play with video.

Try this command.

```
exec("ffmpeg -i filePath/fileName.ext filePath/newFileName.mp4");
```

You can set your other preset also.

Comment: "ffmpeg -i path newPath"